# BlogEngine.Net - "Unable to generate a temporary class" error

Tags: blogengine.net

I just uploaded a new instance of blogengine.net to a subdomain on my host and I am getting the following error:

> Unable to generate a temporary class
>   (result=1). error CS2001: Source file
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jn5ced1y.0.cs' could
>   not be found error CS2008: No inputs
>   specified

I do have  VPS plan on my host, do I need to ask for specific permissions?

On previous installs (older versions) of BE I never had this problem - did I do something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue on the TEMP directory. I've had the same issue locally on my development machine and took the naughty EVERYONE/ALL route to resolve.